# My terminal in VS Code has a tiny font after installing zsh and changing font style

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, zsh, font-size

If you look at the VS Code terminal - its too tiny.

Here're the user settings that I have modified to create this result.  I have searched how to change terminal fonts at VS Code, but I have followed all instructions pertaining to
`terminal.integrated.fontSize` and this doesn't help at all - it only lengthens the line.

Please advise - thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I'm sure there are a few answers to this.  But to solve mine, I had to change the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily`. Try these themes "Monaco" for instance.  Add this line to your settings.

```json
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Monaco"
```

If the font size does not change and only increases the letter spacing, try a few checks:

1. Save the settings and close VS Code editor and re-open a new one.
2. Try restarting VS Code.
3. The Font family theme that you select plays a huge role in how it renders.
4. Check this [font family themes](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) that you can test.

This is my current setting as far as basic visuals for CLI and the editor:

```json
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
"workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
"editor.fontFamily": "Monaco",
"editor.fontSize": 12,
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Hack",
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
"terminal.integrated.lineHeight":1,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
```

Again, these are checks you can do. I hope this helps cause it definitely took me a while to change my view of VS Code terminal above to the one I have below now:

[image]

Comment: How do I change `terminal.integrated.fontFamily`? Where is this setting file?

Comment: If I typed this in the setting search bar it says: Controls the font family of the terminal, this defaults to Editor: Font Family's value.

Comment: @AeroWang this is in settings.json, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Comment: I had to change the font to `monospace` on ubuntu.

Answer (score 29):

Code > Preferences > Settings > Features > Terminal. Here you can find Integrated: Font Size and change it to your desired size

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Go to Terminal >> Settings >>> font size as described in above screen shot and try updating desired font size and weight

Answer (score 11):

Set the `terminal.integrated.fontsize` in your user settings to override the original value. I have mine set to **20**.  I am old ;)

Comment: Your right and Ive tried that.  But during those times, i was using a font family that is not vscode's default font.  So changing fontsize just increased the line spacing.  Probably fixed now, but try experimenting with different font family and you may still encounter what I have encountered then.  To fix that, you need to change font family.

Answer (score 8):

Code > Preferences > Settings > Search "terminal font size" on the bar > change font size

Answer (score 3):

Also use **[FontSize Shortcuts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fosshaas.fontsize-shortcuts)**, then

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for incrementation font size,

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for decrementation font size.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Command Palette:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
macOS: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Enter **Open Settings (JSON)**

Add `terminal.integrated.fontSize` to the file.

All you have to do is add this line to the file and save:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16
```

Answer (score -1):

Just zoom the whole VS Code's UI in or out with CTRL + + or CTRL + - respectively and than adjust font sizes we do have control over in settings.json file.

Use Ctrl + + for incrementation font size,

Use Ctrl + - for decrementation font size.

Comment: Use Ctrl + + for incrementation font size,

Use Ctrl + - for decrementation font size.