# Cannot install font on vscode so that zsh displays properly (using linux manjaro)

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, themes, manjaro

This question help me solve the problem when I was using ubuntu:

[My terminal in VSCode has a tiny font after installing zsh and changing font style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096501/my-terminal-in-vscode-has-a-tiny-font-after-installing-zsh-and-changing-font-sty)

I cannot make it work when using manjaro. In fact after installing `Menlo for Powerline` font my terminal looks like this:
[image]
(picture looks blurry because I reduced its size)

The font I am trying to use is `Menlo for Powerline` and it can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline

### This is what I am doing:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline.git

# for some reason I do not have this directory
# I have also perform the same steps using the directory /usr/share/fonts
mkdir ~/.fonts

# copy all the fonts to the new directory just created
cp ~/Downloads/Menlo-for-Powerline/* ~/.fonts/

# make sure fonts are in here
cd ~/.fonts
ls

# update fonts cache
fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts
```

I then set setting `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` to

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Menlo for Powerline",
```

when I do that vscode shows warning saying

> "The terminal only supports monospace fonts. Be sure to restart VS
> Code if this is a newly installed font."

**I restart VS Code and the font does not work still! I guess my problem is that I am placing the font in some incorrect place. Ubuntu places its fonts on ~/.fonts but what about manjaro?**

Comment: https://blog.zhaytam.com/2019/04/19/powerline-and-zshs-agnoster-theme-in-vs-code/ I have also tried that link and it does not work

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I am struggling with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try copying your fonts to /usr/share/fonts/TTF. You can also try installing the fonts (which file managers like nautilus and nemo support)

Answer (score 0):

Fist install font with command:

```
sudo pacman -S ttf-meslo-nerd-font-powerlevel10k
```

Then open vscode and go to the terminal tab. With the terminal open inside Vscode (look for an arrow on the side of this *+*(new terminal). Select the *configure terminal settings* option. Click is a filter on the right side, look for font and copy and paste this font ('MesloLGS NF', 'monospace', monospace).
In the option just below *Font Ligatures*, click on edit in settings.json and change it from false to true.

Now Reload window.